# $.post and alert() issues

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, alert

I have a a form that I am using jQuery $.post to grab form data and send it to a php script. The script then sends back some data. The issue I am having is that sometimes (10% of the time maybe) when the submit button is clicked on the form the alert box won't appear? It work's almost always but the odd time no alert box is displayed yet if the form passes the php validation checks the data is still entered. Is it a timing issue? I noticed as well that when testing on mobile the alerts do not display at all. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var jsonObj;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(){
        var wScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('wScore').value);
        var lScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('lScore').value);
        var errors = 0;
        if(lScore > wScore){
            errors = 1;
        }
        if(errors != 0){
            alert('Winnings runs MUST be greater than losing runs.');
            return false;
        }
        var selNameW = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1");
        document.getElementById("textWinner").value = selNameW.options[selNameW.selectedIndex].text;
        var selNameL = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1");
        document.getElementById("textLoser").value = selNameL.options[selNameL.selectedIndex].text;
        $.post('query.php',$('#form').serialize()) 
            .done(function(data){
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                if(jsonObj.status == 'error'){
                    alert(jsonObj.errorMessage);
                }else{
                    alert("Successfully Entered! Winner: " + jsonObj.winner + " Loser: " + jsonObj.loser);
                }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php 

include "dbconnect.php";

$jsonData = [];

extract($_POST);

$exampleInputEmail1 = intval($exampleInputEmail1);
$exampleInputPassword1 = intval($exampleInputPassword1);

$qqq = "SELECT * FROM games WHERE winner = '$exampleInputEmail1' AND game_date = '$inputDate' AND loser = '$exampleInputPassword1'";

$result = $conn->query($qqq);


if($password !== 'slopitch19'){
        $error = ['status' => 'error', 'errorMessage' => 'The password is incorrect or was left blank!'];
        $jsonData = json_encode($error);
    }

else if(empty($inputDate) || empty($wScore) || empty($lScore) || empty($password)){
    $error = ['status' => 'error', 'errorMessage' => 'A field was left blank.'];
    $jsonData = json_encode($error);
}

else if($exampleInputEmail1 == $exampleInputPassword1){
    $error = ['status' => 'error', 'errorMessage' => 'The winning team cannot be the same as the losing team.'];
    $jsonData = json_encode($error);
}

else if ($result->num_rows == 0){
    $sql2 = "INSERT INTO games (winner, loser, game_date, winner_name, loser_name, winner_score, loser_score) VALUES ('$exampleInputEmail1', '$exampleInputPassword1','$inputDate', '$textWinner', '$textLoser', '$wScore', '$lScore')";

    $sql = "UPDATE teams SET wins = wins + 1 WHERE team_id = '$exampleInputEmail1'";

    $sql3 = "UPDATE teams SET losses = losses + 1 WHERE team_id = '$exampleInputPassword1'";

    $values = ['status' => 'success', 'winner' => $textWinner, 'loser' => $textLoser];

    $jsonData = json_encode($values);

    $conn->query($sql);
    $conn->query($sql3);
    $conn->query($sql2);

    $conn->close();

}else if($result->num_rows > 0){
        $error = ['status' => 'error', 'errorMessage' => 'Someone else has already entered this game!'];
        $jsonData = json_encode($error);
}

echo $jsonData;




    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe you dont have an error handler in your php file and because of that it get stuck and never respond back to the client side and thats why you never reach the alert inside your done ? can you show your php code ?

Comment: JQuery's .post() method also have an error handler. You are not handling errors in your JQuery. Look at the docs here: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: open your dev tools and see if there are console errors, or an error in the ajax call. Did you do any debugging yet?

Comment: I added a .fail function that alerts "error", still didn't seem to fix the problem 100%. Although, now on mobile every time submit is pressed it alerts error. It works almost every time still on pc browser. Just once in a blue moon no alert box. I debugged, no errors or warnings that i can find in chrome debugger.

Comment: Fail holds helpful details on failure, so don't just alert("error") do .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) { alert("Post error: " + error); });

Comment: @NawedKhan when I do this the alert box is empty

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission `$('#form').submit(function(event){ event.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. I think for some reason mobile browsers especially have an issue with jQuery $.post

Changing to $.ajax worked as follows:

```
var jsonObj;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var wScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('wScore').value);
        var lScore = parseInt(document.getElementById('lScore').value);
        var errors = 0;
        if(lScore > wScore){
            errors = 1;
        }
        if(errors != 0){
            alert('Winnings runs MUST be greater than losing runs.');
            return false;
        }
        var selNameW = document.getElementById("exampleInputEmail1");
        document.getElementById("textWinner").value = selNameW.options[selNameW.selectedIndex].text;
        var selNameL = document.getElementById("exampleInputPassword1");
        document.getElementById("textLoser").value = selNameL.options[selNameL.selectedIndex].text;
        $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'query.php',
           data: $('#form').serialize(),  
           success: function(data){
                jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
                if(jsonObj.status == 'error'){
                    alert(jsonObj.errorMessage);
                }else{
                    alert("Successfully Entered! Winner: " + jsonObj.winner + " Loser: " + jsonObj.loser);
                }
           }
        });
    });
});
```